# Hw can I embed a calendar as input mode to a date text box for a user t select the appropriate date?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML form that requests for input for date of birth through a text box. But instead of asking the user t type the date as `DD/MM/YYYY` or `DD-MM-YYYY` or writing long codes for `<select><option></option></select>`, I wuld like to use a calender box which would appear on clicking a button or on the textbox itself & allow the user t select the right date & aut-format it as mentioned above and fill the text box.

Please prvide example codes in `HTML or PHP or JS or JQUERY`...

Thanks !!!

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using HTML5 compatible browsers or mobile (anything in the last few years) you can just use:

```
Birthday: <input type="date" name="bday">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V6MnL/

Depending on your backend language... I know in PHP you can say..

```
<?php $birthday = date("m-d-y",strtotime("01-12-2014")); ?>
```

which yeilds `12-01-14`

Hope that helps, I'm sure most backends have that type of extraction and formating

Comment: Oh !! Thanks :) This is really simple... But what if we need to change the format???? E.G. `MM-DD-YY` or `MM/DD/YY` (Nte: `YY` not `YYYY`)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

[jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Read http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

[**`Fiddle Demo`**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Fa8Xx/1527/)